# How to create a new command which will box every letter of two words

Tags: conditionals, columns, characters

I've done lots of programming in other languages but very new to LaTeX.

Best to refer to the document below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

Version 1

\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c |}
  \hline            
  A & B & C & D & E \\\hline            
    & G & H &   &   \\\hline            
\end{tabular}
\\
\\

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\stringprocess}{ m m }
 {
  \egreg_string_process:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_string_process:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 } { #1 { ##1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\boxchar}[1]{#1 &}

\newcommand{\boxwords}[2]{
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
  \hline            
  \stringprocess{\boxchar}{#1}
  \\\hline
  \stringprocess{\boxchar}{#2}
  \\\hline  
\end{tabular}
}

Version 2

\boxwords{ABCDE}{ GH  }
\\
\\

Version 3

\boxwords{ABCDE}{.GH..}
\\
\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Version 1 comes out as I would want it.
But I want to create a new command to allow easier syntax.
Rather than type all the individual letters I want to just give the two words.
So I want to just type: `\boxwords{ABCDE}{.GH..}`
to produce the same boxed words.

My first attempt is Version 2.

Issue A:
There's an extra column on the end with blank. I understand that this comes from the trailing `&` on the last letter of each word. In other programming languages I'd know how to suppress this last & at the end of the loop but not sure how to do this in Latex?

Issue B:
I don't want the dots to appear.
I just wanted them to be placeholders in the input to the function so that they come out as spaces.

I tried just putting the spaces in directly in Version 3 but rather than cause empty boxes, the spaces cause boxes to be missed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is `\seq_use:Nn` for producing the table rows. First we set sequences containing the two items (after changing `.` into `\relax`), make their length equal and print the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\boxwords}{mm}
 {
  \suhada_boxwords:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_suhada_boxwords_a_seq
\seq_new:N \l_suhada_boxwords_b_seq
\tl_new:N \l_suhada_boxwords_temp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \suhada_boxwords:nn
 {
  % replace . with \scan_stop: in the first argument
  % and set the first sequence
  \tl_set:Nn \l_suhada_boxwords_temp_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_suhada_boxwords_temp_tl { . } { \scan_stop: }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_suhada_boxwords_a_seq { } \l_suhada_boxwords_temp_tl
  % replace . with \scan_stop: in the first argument
  % and set the first sequence
  \tl_set:Nn \l_suhada_boxwords_temp_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_suhada_boxwords_temp_tl { . } { \scan_stop: }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_suhada_boxwords_b_seq { } \l_suhada_boxwords_temp_tl
  % make the same number of items in both sequences
  \int_compare:nT
   {
    \seq_count:N \l_suhada_boxwords_a_seq < \seq_count:N \l_suhada_boxwords_b_seq
   }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn
     {
      \seq_count:N \l_suhada_boxwords_b_seq - \seq_count:N \l_suhada_boxwords_a_seq
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_suhada_boxwords_a_seq { \scan_stop: }
     }
   }
  \int_compare:nT
   {
    \seq_count:N \l_suhada_boxwords_b_seq < \seq_count:N \l_suhada_boxwords_a_seq
   }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn
     {
      \seq_count:N \l_suhada_boxwords_a_seq - \seq_count:N \l_suhada_boxwords_b_seq
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l_suhada_boxwords_b_seq { \scan_stop: }
     }
   }
  % print the table
  \begin{tabular}{|*{\seq_count:N \l_suhada_boxwords_a_seq}{c|}}
  \hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l_suhada_boxwords_a_seq { & } \\
  \hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l_suhada_boxwords_b_seq { & } \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\boxwords{ABCDE}{.GH}

\bigskip

\boxwords{ABCDE}{.GH..}

\bigskip

\boxwords{ABC..}{.GH.I}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg for your reply - works really well.
I like your defensive programming style - for instance allowing for strings to be different length.

Comment: The line:
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_suhada_boxwords_temp_tl { . } { \scan_stop: }
solves my problem of replacing the dots.

I also want to replace some other characters.

I want to replace * with the multiply symbol.

To test the principle I tried adding:

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_suhada_boxwords_temp_tl { * } { m }

and that works fine.

I tried:

\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_suhada_boxwords_temp_tl { * } { $\times$ }

but I get an error: Extra }, or forgotten $.

Can't see what is wrong?

Comment: @Suhada You need braces around `$\times$`, so it is considered a single item when the splitting takes place: `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_suhada_boxwords_temp_tl { * } { {$\times$} }`

Answer (score 2):

Expl3 has [booleans](http://mirror.unicorncloud.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#page=51) which can be used similar to the bools from other languages. To create the empty boxes, you can use `{}` for empty groups.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N\l_is_first_bool
\NewDocumentCommand{\stringprocess}{ m m }
 {
   \bool_set_true:N\l_is_first_bool
   \tl_map_inline:nn{#2}{#1{##1}\l_is_first_bool\bool_set_false:N\l_is_first_bool}
 }

 \newcommand{\boxchar}[2]{\bool_if:NTF#2{}{&}#1}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\boxwords}[2]{
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
  \hline            
  \stringprocess{\boxchar}{#1}
  \\\hline
  \stringprocess{\boxchar}{#2}
  \\\hline  
\end{tabular}
}

Version 2

\boxwords{ABCDE}{{}GH{}{}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks zauguin for your reply - helps me understand more about how latex programming works.  I've decided to go with the sequence approach as it fits with my further development.